# Compass sprite-map variable name?

Tags: compass-sass

This is my current SASS file:

```
$icons-spacing: 12px;
$icons-sprite-dimensions: true;
@import "sprites/icons/*.png";
@include all-icons-sprites;

.odd .chat-marker { background-position: sprite-position($icons, chat-marker-inverted); }
```

Error: `Undefined variable "$icons"`

So what's the sprite map's variable? The map config variables at the top work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution using the generated mixins, like this:

```
.odd .icons-chat-marker { @include icons-sprite(chat-marker-inverted); }
```

Comment: Did you manage to ever find out how to get a reference to the actual sprite $map? I have a situation where I specifically need to use `sprite-position()`.